# Creating an extension method in C#

Tags: c#, extension-methods, html-helper

I'm trying to create an extension method in C# for the HtmlHelper class. I've read the MSDN page for it, and I'm sure I'm referencing the correct namespaces. I wonder what I could be doing wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc; //Correctly referencing the necessary namespaces, right?

namespace MvcApplication1.HelperMethods
{
    public static class NavigationalMenu
    {
        public static string MyMenu(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {
            CategoryRepository categoryRepo = new CategoryRepository();
            var categories = categoryRepo.FindAllCategories();

            foreach (Category c in categories)
            {
                helper.RouteLink(blablabla); //Construct links and return them.
            }

            //helper.RouteLink doesn't show up! C# wipeouuuuuttttt.
            //It's as if 'helper' doesn't have the RouteLink method there.
        }
    }
}
```

First time that this happens to me when programming in C#. Anyone else encounter this problem?

Comment: If you think I'm trolling, try this code in your own IDE. If you find a solution please share! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493095%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> Extensions to the HtmlHelper class are
>   located in the System.Web.Mvc.Html
>   namespace. These extensions add helper
>   methods for creating forms, rendering
>   HTML controls, rendering partial
>   views, input validation, and more.

Trying including the `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace. [LinkExtensions.RouteLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470205%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) gives its namespace as that (it says it's in `System.Web.Mvc.dll`, just in a different namespace).

Comment: This solved my problem. I had to add the namespaces for both Mvc and Mvc.Html. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference `System.Web.Mvc` for the `HtmlHelper`, but the extension is in `System.Web.Mvc.Html`.

Answer (score 0):

Your namespace may be wrong.  Try `using System.Web.Mvc.Html`;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(VS.90).aspx

Comment: I added the more specific namespace like you suggested, but now the variable type isn't even recognized. Do you think I found a bug in MVC3? Why else wouldn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure add the namespace see the resukt System.Web.Mvc.Html